# Can Avast check my WI-FI password for strength?

Tags: passwords, wifi, antivirus

I've been greeted by this popup this morning:

[image]

Can Avast actually check my WI-FI password for strength? Or is it just "marketing scare" so that I upgrade to the paid version instead of using the free version? If it's a real notification message, how does it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows stores the Wi-Fi password in reversible format. A simple Google query for "how does Windows store Wi-Fi passwords" returns [this article](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/view-saved-wifi-passwords-windows/), which doesn't answer the question at all, but shows that Windows can at least display the original password.

That means that your Anti-Virus Software, which runs with elevated rights, can read out your Wi-Fi password and then run some checks against it.

For example, if your Wi-Fi password were `zxcvbnm12345`, it may detect the pattern behind and report it as weak.

Comment: Yes it is correct, you can manually click the right buttons (Adapters, settings, security, show password, etc) or type `netsh wlan show profile key=clear` or something like that and you'll get the password for that Wi-Fi network.